# Heuristically, how can we visualize a tangent measure?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Heuristically, how can we visualize a [tangent measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_measure)?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_measure#Examples) makes an example in the case of the Hausdorff measure on the circle in $\mathbb R^2$, but I'm interested in visual examples in more general circumstances.